# Debug deep into nodeJs source

Tags: eclipse, node.js, nodeclipse

## enide - In Node.js Eclipse IDE, how can i include the source code for debugging node inbuilt modules like `fs, eventemitter, http`, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make debugger stop on the first line (see -brk option in Preferences),
then in appeared V8 sources search for module you need

Comment: it worked Paul, nodeclipse rocks... again, when stack traces are printed on eclipse console, if they are given as links to the code, it will ease our debugging... at present, those are plain texts and users need to manually find the file, and go to the desired line number.